# Listing images in an array from given url

Tags: swift, macos

I'm working on a tool to ease batch renaming images, using a folder chooser (NSOpenPanel), i want to pass the returned path, get all jpeg files in that (local) folder and put them in an array so i can go trough it, preview them and eventually copy and rename them to a new folder.
I have only found things for iOS, nothing for MacOS.
Any ideas or guidelines on where to look further are welcome. Thank you!

This is the basic idea:

```
let dialog = NSOpenPanel();

    dialog.title                   = "Choose raw images folder";
    dialog.showsResizeIndicator    = true;
    dialog.showsHiddenFiles        = false;
    dialog.canChooseFiles = false;
    dialog.canChooseDirectories = true;
    
    if (dialog.runModal() ==  NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK) {
        let result = dialog.url

        if (result != nil) {
            let rawFilePath: String = result!.path
            // how to do this
            getImages(path: rawFilePath)
 
        }
    } else {
        // Dialog cancelled
        return;
    }
```

Comment: The `FileManager` APIs are similar and in many cases, identical between macOS and iOS. Are you just asking how to list the files in the given directory?

Comment: I didn't know they were so similar, i'll have a look at that as well